# Finding MSLE in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I am trying to see the MSLE loss of my test dataset in **TensorFlow Keras** in a regression model.

I tried using:

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(model.predict(X_test), Y_test)

print(loss)
```

But instead of getting the loss, it is displayed:

```
tensorflow.python.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError object at 0x000001DC80545668
```

How can I find the loss of my test dataset in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MeanSquaredLogarithmicError` is a class and has to be [instantiated](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) before performing the loss calculation, e.g.:

```
msle = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError()
loss = msle(model.predict(X_test), Y_test)
```

See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredLogarithmicError) for further information.

Comment: I tried that and get printed: Tensor("MeanSquaredLogarithmicError_2/weighted_loss/Cast:0", shape=(), dtype=float64)

Comment: This is your resulting `Tensor` object. As shown in the linked docs, you can get the value using `loss.numpy()`. Also have a look at [Tensors](https://medium.com/@ecaradec/understanding-keras-tensors-d405a63e069e).

Comment: loss.numpy() gives me - AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Comment: I found out how to show the loss anyways with a different method, msle = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError()
loss = msle(model.predict(X_test), Y_test)

sess = tf.Session()


sess.run(loss)